# Error with a RouteValue string that has the same name as an Action Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I originally had the following code inside a view:

```
return RedirectToAction("Error", new { error = "User Already Exists" });
```

This caused the View not found error:

[image]

Changing the code to the following works fine:

```
return RedirectToAction("Error", new { errorid = "User Already Exists" });
```

Considering both are just string names, I am sure I am calling the same overload in both cases, but, I just can't understand what is wrong here / why it thinks I need a different view.

What have I done wrong?

---

@SLaks' Request -

```
    public ActionResult Error(string errorid)
    {
        ViewBag.error = errorid;

        return View();
    }
```

(before, errorid was simply just error)

Comment: Please show us your `Error` action.

Comment: @SLaks ... Argh... I think this may be a mystery that I will have to leave. I thought this was a bug, but, before I posted here, I changed it back and fourth several times and was able to reproduce EVERY time... but, I just tried putting it back - and... typical... I can't reproduce it. :( I think I will leave it as errorid for now as I don't want to tempt fate, but, I will try again when I have a bit more time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What most likely happened is your `Error` method was constructed like

```
public ActionResult Error(string errorid) {
    ViewBag.error = errorid;

    return View(errorid);
}
```

instead of you using the `ViewBag`. This will cause the exact error that occurred. You probably had your model as `@model string`. The reason this would fail and cause that error is because the signature for `View(string)` assumes you're passing in which view (and not the model) you want to see. In this case to fix it you'll want to do something like `return View("Error", errorid);` where the second parameter is your model.

Comment: I did originally have this and could have sworn that I still got the error after removing it... but, I put it back and was able to recreate the error. I never had @model string, and, I can recreate the problem without that. I understand what happened now and feel like someone should post the epic facepalm picture! Thanks +1 and answer.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.Net MVC matches routes to actions using parameter names.

Therefore, the parameter names in the route / URL must exactly match the action's parameters.

Comment: Sorry, I do not think I was clear enough in the question, I have modified it.